# Find the minimum absolute values along the third dimension in a 3D matrix and ensuring the sign is maintained

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a `m X n X k` matrix and I want to find the elements that have minimal absolute value along the third dimension for each unique 2D spatial coordinate.  An additional constraint is that once I find these minimum values, the sign of these values (i.e. before I took the absolute value) must be maintained.

The code I wrote to accomplish this is shown below.

```
tmp = abs(dist); %the size(dist)=[m,n,k]
[v,ind] = min(tmp,[],3); %find the index of minimal absolute value in the 3rd dimension
ind = reshape(ind,m*n,1);
[col,row]=meshgrid(1:n,1:m); row = reshape(row,m*n,1); col = reshape(col,m*n,1);     
ind2 = sub2ind(size(dist),row,col,ind); % row, col, ind are sub
dm = dist(ind2); %take the signed value from dist
dm = reshape(dm,m,n);
```

The resulting matrix `dm` which is `m X n` corresponds to the matrix that is subject to the constraints that I have mentioned previously. However, this code sounds a little bit inefficient since I have to generate linear indices. Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: `min(abs(dist),[],3)`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Yuanhao The first two lines of code are already doing that.  Do you want to also respect the original sign of the minimum values once you find them?  That's what your code is doing for the rest.

Comment: HI rayryeng, yes, I also need the sign. The rest code is doing that but not efficient as I point out, because I always need to switch between sub and index, which is annoying.

Comment: That makes more sense.  Let me formulate an answer. One moment please.

Comment: @LuisMendo Hi Luis, `min(abs(dist),[],3)` only gives the minimal absolute value. I need the elements that have the minimal absolute value. So, it could be negative. The first two lines of my code find the index of the minimal absolute value while the rest tries to find the sign.

Comment: @Yuanhao I've written an answer.  I've also taken the liberty in editing your question so that this point is made clear.  It wasn't in your first draft, which made Luis and myself (initially) confused.

Comment: @rayryeng, thanks for making it clear! I hope it is also clearer for others. I noticed your answer, but it is essentially the same as my code. no?

Comment: @Yuanhao yes, but you have unnecessary operations.  However, you unfortunately have no way of doing what you want without resorting to linear indices.

Comment: I see. I hadn't understood your question. Then @rayryeng's answer does what you want

Comment: @rayryeng, Thanks for pointing it out! Indeed, I don't need reshape operations. It is surprising that we need more code to find the sign, compared with the 'min' function that finds the minimum value.

Comment: @Yuanhao you're welcome! For sure and I agree with you. I tried a couple of other solutions but they didn't work. The only proper solution I could think of was to generate the linear indices of the corresponding locations and to sample from those locations. I hope to be proven wrong, but this is the only thing I could think of. Let me know if you need any more help. If you don't and if my answer did help you, consider accepting my answer to let the community know you no longer need help. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

If I'm interpreting your problem statement correctly, you wish to find the minimum absolute value along the third dimension for each unique 2D spatial coordinate in your 3D matrix.  This is already being done by the first two lines of your code.

However, a small caveat is that once you find these minimum values, you must ensure that the original sign of these values (i.e. before taking the absolute value) are respected.  That is the purpose of the rest of the code.

If you want to select the original values, you don't have a choice but to generate the correct linear indices and sample from the original matrix.  However, a lot of code is rather superfluous.  There is no need to perform any kind of reshaping.

We can simplify your method by using [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate the correct spatial coordinates to sample from the 3D matrix then use `ind` from your code to reference the third dimension.  After, use this to sample `dist` and complete your code:

```
%// From your code
[v,ind] = min(abs(dist),[],3); 

%// New code
[row,col] = ndgrid(1:size(dist,1), 1:size(dist,2));

%// Output
dm = dist(sub2ind(size(dist), row, col, ind));
```